# Win32: Get info on statically linked libraries

Tags: winapi, static-libraries, reverse-engineering

Assuming you only have access to the final product (i.e. in form of the exe file), how would you go about finding out which libraries/components the developer used to create the application?

In my specific case the question is about an application developed in VC++ using a few third party components and I'm curious which those are.

But I think the question is generally valid, e.g. when it should be proven if a developer is in line with license requirements of a specific library.

Comment: You can't. A binary that is the result of static linking of libraries does not contain any import tables (except for those, that couldn't be resolved, usually system libraries like *kernel32.dll*). You can only try to find patterns in the final executable image, that maps to known object code in static libraries.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that if I suspect that a binary is using a certain library, I could try to map the respective function calls and see if I get a result. But there is no shortcut to this and unless I am willing to try out hundreds of mappings or the dev left some information in some strings or other resources, I have little chance of finding this out. Yes?

Comment: Strings won't get compiled into the .text segment, so that doesn't change the object code, and cannot obfuscate it.

Comment: You can use patterns like window class names, object names, leftover debug symbols, etc.; if all else fails, you will need to reverse-engineer or compare known binaries of the library in question with the executable. In addition, if you suspect that a proprietary application is using a free software library in a way that violates the free software license, there are several organizations that can also help.

Comment: Speaking of strings, they can serve as a rough estimate. They are compiled into the .bss segment. Inspecting the .bss segment for strings literals that you expect can in fact serve as a first guess. [DUMPBIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) is one of the tools you'll want to get familiar with.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm already using CFF Explorer and PE Viewer, in addition to ASM debuggers, probably not much more Dumpbin can give me, right? Anyway, thanks to both of you for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

> So, what you're saying is that if I suspect that a binary is using a certain library, I could try to map the respective function calls and see if I get a result. But there is no shortcut to this and unless I am willing to try out hundreds of mappings or the dev left some information in some strings or other resources, I have little chance of finding this out. Yes?

There is small shortcut, here's what I'd do:

1. check executable for strings and constants, and try to find out what library is that.
2. IF used libraries are open-source, compile them on my own and create FLAIR signatures (IDA Pro).
3. Use generated flair signatures on target executable.

In some situations, that can really work like a charm and can let you distinguish actual code from used libraries.

[The IDA Pro Book - Ch 12. Library Recognition Using FLIRT Signatures](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781593273750/library_recognition_using_flirt_signatur)